# google drive Api not working in production "Failed to launch browser with"

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

i'm facing an issue with google drive API, it is working on my local machine, but once i deploy the project to the server, the google drive API service stops working,
it is throwing an oauth2 exception, i think i need to do something on the google drive api console but i don't know what it is or where to start
the credentiels i'm currently using are OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and client Secret, type Desktop.

please any help is appreciated

here is the exception i get.

```
  An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=813040219774-atf2l4751d1tkjeegoeb7d4lituel9ev.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42257%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=813040219774-atf2l4751d1tkjeegoeb7d4lituel9ev.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42257%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=813040219774-atf2l4751d1tkjeegoeb7d4lituel9ev.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42257%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
ElseForty.FileServices.Files+GoogleDrive.GetService() in Files.cs
ElseForty.FileServices.Files+GoogleDrive.UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file) in Files.cs
ElseForty.Controllers.BugReportController.Send(User_BugReportViewModel model) in BugReportController.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=813040219774-atf2l4751d1tkjeegoeb7d4lituel9ev.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42257%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.AuthorizeAsync(string userId, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)

Show raw exception details
```

**UPDATE**

i'm using the google drive api for my web application for visitor to upload images,

```
          public static DriveService GetService()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
              new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "elsefortydisk",
            });
        }

        public static async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var fileName = GetUniqueFileName(file.FileName);
            var service = GetService();
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            fileMetadata.MimeType = file.ContentType;
            fileMetadata.Parents = new List<string>() { "14kECd48VL6xhS9ArQL3Lh7oLT6npAVg-" };

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, file.ContentType);

                request.Fields = "id";
                await request.UploadAsync();
            }
            var responce = request.ResponseBody;
            var pemission = new Permission();
            pemission.Type = "anyone";
            pemission.Role = "reader";
            try
            {
                service.Permissions.Create(pemission, responce.Id).Execute();  
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }

            return responce.Id;
        }
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]  without seeing your code its hard to help

Comment: Hi @DaImTo i have included some code above, hope this can help you better understand what i'm trying to do , 
thanx

Comment: I have updated my answer to better explain why you cant use **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** for web applications and to show you how your should have coded your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues You Have your question tagged asp.net core and you state that you are uploading it to a server.   Yet you have also stated that you have created a desktop client on google developer console

> am currently using are OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and client Secret, type Desktop.

If you are using asp .net core then you are creating a web application and should there for have created web browsers credentials.

The code you are using was desngied for an installed / desktop application where the code is run on the machine the user is using.  Example You are using  `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` which is intended for use with installed applications.  The way it is designed it opens the browser window on the machine that its running on which is why you are seeing the following error message.

> NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=813040219774-atf2l4751d1tkjeegoeb7d4lituel9ev.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42257%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.

Your code works locally because it is able to open the browser window on the machine its running when run on a web server it will attempt to open the web browser consent window on the web server which is not what you want it to be doing you want it to be opening the browser consent on the users client machine.

If you are trying to create a web application using Asp .net core then you need to create web application credentials, and configure the web application as follows.

Configuring an asp.net core application to access the google apis is quite different i have a tutorial on it here which will walk you though the configuration of the setup however [Asp .net core 3 and Google login](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)

```
// This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
 services
     .AddAuthentication(o =>
     {
         // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
         // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
         o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
         // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
         o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
         // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
         o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
       .AddCookie()
       .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
       {
          options.ClientId = ClientId;
          options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
           });
```

Calling the api itself which will request authorization is mainly done with an attribute.

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DriveFileList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    var files = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
    var fileNames = files.Files.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return View(fileNames);
}
```

## Tip

Desktop / installed applications are designed to run on a single machine that the user is in front of and using.

Web applications are run from web servers and the user contacts them though a web browser.

These are two different types of applications and the clients created on google developer console are different as is the code to use each of these clients they cant be mixed.

Comment: If your interested i have a sample project i could put up on GitHub for Google drive api with asp .net core

Comment: thanx, yes please that would help alot,   
 i made some changes and it seams like it is half working, i changed the application type to web application," it was desktop before". 
 i also changed the code to request a drive service instance to fit the new application type, but now i'm redirected to this URL after user signin. 
http://mywebsite.com/signin-oidc.   
i don't have this controller "signin-oidc" in my project, i want the users to go to "google drive upload image" action instead. 
how can i do that?

Comment: [Google Drive Asp .Net core sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/GoogleAspNetCoreSamples)  The way Oauth works is that your application will be uploading the image the users wont need to go to Google Drive to upload the image you can do it for them once they have granted your application access to their drive account.   Please remember that Google drive is considered restricted scopes your going to have to go though a security audit when you apply for verification of this application.  [What you need to know about application verification in 2021](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)

Comment: i see, it looks like the process is not what i'm looking for, i don't want my users to be requested to grant any permissions when they simply want to upload an image, this will look super suspecious , i'll drop this and upload everything to my server i guess, thank you for your great help